# Is canvas getImageData method machine/browser dependent?

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors, getimagedata

A client required help with a program that extracts the dominant color of a product image.

I was able to quickly implement this in Javascript; the algorithm below only samples the central square of a 3x3 grid on the image for a quick estimate of the t-shirt color in the image.

```js
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function() {
    try {
        // get dominant color by sampling the central square of a 3x3 grid on image
        var dominantColor = getDominantColor();

        // output color
        $("#output").html(dominantColor);
    }
    catch(e) {
        $("#output").html(e);
    }
};
image.src = "sample_image.jpg";

function getDominantColor() {

    // Copy image to canvas
    var canvas = $("<canvas/>")[0];
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0);

    // get pixels from the central square of a 3x3 grid
    var imageData = canvas.getContext("2d").getImageData(canvas.width/3, canvas.height/3, canvas.width/3, canvas.height/3).data;

    var colorOccurrences = {};
    var dominantColor = "";
    var dominantColorOccurrence = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < imageData.length; i += 4) {
        var red = imageData[i];
        var green = imageData[i+1];
        var blue = imageData[i+2];
        //var alpha = imageData[i+3]; // not required for this task

        var color = RGBtoHEX({"red": red, "green": green, "blue": blue});

        if(colorOccurrences[color] == undefined) {
            colorOccurrences[color] = 1;
        }
        else {
            colorOccurrences[color] ++;

            if(colorOccurrences[color] > dominantColorOccurrence) {
                dominantColorOccurrence = colorOccurrences[color];
                dominantColor = color;
            }
        }
    }

    return dominantColor;
}

function RGBtoHEX(rgb) {
    var hexChars = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    return "#"
            + (hexChars[~~(rgb.red/16)] + hexChars[rgb.red%16])
            + (hexChars[~~(rgb.green/16)] + hexChars[rgb.green%16])
            + (hexChars[~~(rgb.blue/16)] + hexChars[rgb.blue%16]);
}
```

The image in question is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gwHI.jpg) (preview below).

[image: Sample product]

However, the results when this image is processed in the code above are varied across machines/browsers: **`#FF635E`** is what I see on my machine, running Windows7 and using Firefox 32. My client running Mac gets a result of **`#FF474B`** on Safari and **`#FF474C`** on Firefox 33.

***Though the results are close, why are they ideally not the exact same?*** Does `getImageData` indeed vary depending on the local setup, or is the JPG data being interpreted differently on different machines?

**Edit**: This image isn't a one-off case. Such color variations were noticed across a range of the image that the client requested to process. My client and I obtained different results for the same set of images.

Comment: This has to do with the browser applying or not a color profile, and which one.

Comment: A third party image processing library that doesn't depend on the browser's canvas functionality might help. For example, [this is a good library](https://github.com/lukeapage/pngjs).

Comment: There are 2 other ways around this. One is to use WebGL and readPixels. WebGL can turn off the color correction by calling `gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_COLORSPACE_CONVERSION_WEBGL, gl.NONE);` before uploading the image. You'd then [render it](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-image-processing.html) and read back the pixels. Another way is to use the [`ImageBitmap` api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap). Unfortunately it looks like only Chrome supports the full spec with options to ignore color space conversions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. This fact is exploited by [canvas fingerprinting](https://www.browserleaks.com/canvas):

> The same HTML5 Canvas element can
>   produce exceptional pixels on a different web browsers, depending on
>   the system on which it was executed.
>
> This happens for several reasons: at the image format level — web
>   browsers uses different image processing engines, export options,
>   compression level, final images may got different hashes even if they
>   are pixel-perfect; at the pixmap level — operating systems use
>   different algorithms and settings for anti-aliasing and sub-pixel
>   rendering. We don't know all the reasons, but we have already
>   collected more than a thousand unique signatures.

Comment: I've seen different results on two almost identical Windows 8 machines (one running Chrome, the other running the latest Opera [Chromium based]).