# canvas2d toDataURL() different output on different browser

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have the same image and the same size of canvas, but the output is different. I want the same output, how should I do it?

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image;

img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';

img.onload = function(){
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.width = img.width;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    setBreakpoint(dataURL);
    callback.call(this, dataURL);
    canvas = null;
};

img.src = url;
```

Comment: you could specify format and compression instead of leaving it to defaults. even that might not give you bit-perfect matching outputs though, as there are many ways to encode the same image in a given format.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is canvas getImageData method machine/browser dependent?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26615580/1529630)

Comment: @Oriol, while clearly related, I don't think it's a dupe since here OP is asking for a way to get the same output. (I already had upvoted your answer there so I can't do it anymore...)

Comment: @Kaiido True, I meant "closely related", and didn't vote to close. My answer there explains why canvas fails, but your answer here explains how it can be done without canvas, +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images drawn onto a canvas are decoded before being drawn, then reencoded when the `toDataURL` method is called.
This process will produce some variations in every browser (e.g some will be able to decode color-profiles embedded in the image while others won't), and even every machine (look at [canvas fingerprinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_fingerprinting) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26615864/3702797) by @Oriol which concern images with transparency). Add to that that every browser will use different encoders/settings for a different tradeoff between speed, size and quality and you arrive at a situation where you can't expect two users to produce the same result from the same input image.

But since all you do with that canvas is to draw an image, you should rather use a [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and its method [`readAsDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL). For external files, you can still use it by first fetching the resource as a Blob.

This will work directly on the binary data of the file, encoding each byte to its base64 representation, and thus you will be sure to have the same result in every browser.

Here is a snippet which will test your browser's conversion against mine's.

```js
fetch("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png")
  .then((resp) => resp.ok && resp.blob())
  .then((blob) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (evt) => {
      if (reader.result === imageDataURL) {
        console.log("same result");
      }
      else {
        console.log("please post a comment stating which browser has such a bug");
      }
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);  
  });

var imageDataURL = "data:image/png;base64,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"
```

---

However for the ones using the canvas for real drawing, as we said above, you can't really have the same results between different UAs. Every method from drawing ones to export ones may produce different results and you would have to actually rewrite all these methods entirely in order to have the exact same results.

For the ones that really need this, a project like [*node-canvas*](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) could help, though it would obviously be a lot less performant than native implementations.

Comment: Thank you！ This is what i want :)